# Top volume T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, items

Up above, I want to transform the first dataset into the latter. The goal is to  order the Numbers by highest volume and then select the TOP 2 Letters among those numbers in descending order by Volume. Any solution in T-SQL? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images. Post texts which others can copy to help you with a query.

Comment: How does `top 2` produce 10 rows of results? What order are the results in since it isn't `by Volume descending`? What have you tried?

Comment: top 2 letters per number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic [limit-per-group](/questions/tagged/limit-per-group) problem, which can be easily solved using a common table expression and `row_number()`.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE
(
    Number int,
    Letter char(1),
    Volume int
);

INSERT INTO @T (Number, Letter, Volume) VALUES
(1,'A',230),
(1,'B',534),
(1,'C',23),
(1,'D',42),
(2,'D',566),
(2,'E',24),
(2,'F',566); 
-- you can add more records but this should be enough for this demonstration
```

Then, use a common table expression with `row_number()` and `max(...) over...` for the groups and order by:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT  Number, 
            Letter, 
            Volume, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY Volume DESC) As rn,
            MAX(Volume) OVER(PARTITION BY Number) As MaxVolume,
    FROM @T
)
```

The query:

```
    SELECT Number, Letter, Volume
    FROM @T
    WHERE rn <= 2
    ORDER BY MaxVolume DESC
```

Results:

```
Number  Letter  Volume
2       D       566
2       F       566
1       B       534
1       A       230
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/SSHF82041)